# NSData - Hebrew decoding

Tags: swift, nsdata, decode, encode, hebrew

I'm trying to parse my JSON file, but the NSData replaces hebrew with this string:

> &%231489;&%231500;&%231497;&%231498;

Code:

```
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: json_url!)
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
var name: String = json["test"]["name"] as! String // name gets the string above
```

How can I decode this string so that hebrew will be shown?

Edit: Tried printing the json output:
code:

```
print(String(data: jsonData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

output:

> Optional("{\"test1\": {\"id\":\"9\",\"area\":\"test1\",\"name\":\"test1\",\"latitude\":\"32.05423\",\"longitude\":\"34.95452\"},\"test2\": {\"id\":\"10\",\"area\":\"test2\",\"name\":\"test2\",\"latitude\":\"32.067452\",\"longitude\":\"34.822404\"},\"בליך\": {\"id\":\"11\",\"area\":\"בליך\",\"name\":\"בליך\",\"latitude\":\"32.055987\",\"longitude\":\"34.817980\"}}")

Printing the string with the encoded prints it fine.

Tried adding the line:

```
jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: String(data: jsonData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

Comment: NSData does not replace anything. What does the original JSON look like? How do you parse it? How do you get the above string?

Comment: I get the above string like this. I want to get it like "בליך"
In addition, when I open the JSON file with Safari, it looks fine, maybe because of the browser's decoder.
@MartinR

Comment: Can you show the JSON input as a string: `print(String(data: jsonData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))`

Comment: @MartinR
Optional("{\"test1\": {\"id\":\"9\",\"area\":\"test1\",\"name\":\"test1\",\"latitude\":\"32.05423\",\"longitude\":\"34.95452\"},\"test2\": {\"id\":\"10\",\"area\":\"test2\",\"name\":\"test2\",\"latitude\":\"32.067452\",\"longitude\":\"34.822404\"},\"&#1489;&#1500;&#1497;&#1498;\": {\"id\":\"11\",\"area\":\"&#1489;&#1500;&#1497;&#1498;\",\"name\":\"&#1489;&#1500;&#1497;&#1498;\",\"latitude\":\"32.055987\",\"longitude\":\"34.817980\"}}")

Comment: @MartinR I have done it